# React native firebase messaging getToken() not working after update new version "^12.0.0"

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Just upgraded to react native firebase (v12.0.0) and `getToken()` doesn't working at all. I got this error.

[image: decription image error]

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue yesterday, after hours of searching I did not find anything on the Internet other than your question, so kept everthing and slept. Today when I started to work again, the issue was resolved, don't know how. This might not be a good/correct answer but try to reconnect yout phone (if using a physical device) or even restart your pc if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an firebase issue. You make sure that clear your watch and reset cache

run on your terminal  npm start -- --reset-cache  or react-native start -- --reset-cache

and watchman watch-del-all

then then build